# Possible MSVC 2013 bug when initializing struct members

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, initializer-list

MSVC 2013 complains about the following code, while it works as expected in g++. Does this look like a bug in MSVC?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct A
{
    double x = 0.0, y = 0.0;
};

int main()
{
    A a{ 1.0, 2.0 };
    return 0;
}
```

Note that changing the `struct` as follows resolves the issue.

```
struct A
{
    double x, y;
};
```

The error message is:

> Error 1   error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from
>   'initializer-list' to 'A'

Comment: What's the compiler's complaint (error message)?

Comment: I see nothing wrong with this code. MSVC is just having a bad hair day.

Comment: What version are you using? [VS 2013](http://i1.blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2015/04/29/c-11-14-17-features-in-vs-2015-rc.aspx) seems starting support non-static data member initializers from VS2013 RC.

Comment: @songyuanyao I am using VS 2013 with Update 4 in Visual Studio Premium version.

Comment: [GCC doesn't accept it](http://rextester.com/MRC69655) either; only [clang does](http://rextester.com/SND40913). I'm pretty sure clang is wrong and the other two are right: the presence of member initializers causes `A` to not be an aggregate, and so it cannot be initialized via [aggregate initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization). It needs a two-parameter constructor, or a constructor taking `initializer_list`

Comment: @Igor Why don't you provide a clear answer ? I was searching for it for an hour already ... If you are right, these are some terrible news for simple structures because I tend to use default initialization everywhere: `struct A
{
    double x{}, y{};
};`

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: Turns out you're having a bad hair day ;)

Comment: @Liviu: I've answered.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: your answer is not correct. Better If you delete this incorrect answer. See my answer

Comment: @Destructor: Do you have a criticism other than that the answer changed in C++14, which the OP is not using? Your answer actually agrees with mine about C++11, which is how this question is tagged.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: oh really sorry didn't notice C++11 tag. sincere apologies !!!

Comment: @Destructor: You are forgiven, disciple. It's actually good to discover that C++14 changed this, so I'll add that as a bootnote.

Comment: @Destructor It not about C++ 11 vs C++ 14 as it is about Visual Studio 2015 (2013 should be even worst)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Actually, Visual Studio is correct.**

Your class is not an aggregate, so aggregate initialisation may not be used on it:

> `[C++11: 8.5.1/1]:` An aggregate is an array or a class (Clause 9) with no user-provided constructors (12.1), no *brace-or-equal-initializers* for non-static data members (9.2), no private or protected non-static data members (Clause 11), no base classes (Clause 10), and no virtual functions (10.3).
>
> ---
>
> `[C++11: 8.5.1/15]:` The initialization that occurs in the forms
>
> ```
> T x(a);
> T x{a};
> ```
>
> as well as in `new` expressions (5.3.4), `static_cast` expressions (5.2.9), functional notation type conversions (5.2.3), and base and member initializers (12.6.2) is called *direct-initialization*.
>
> ---
>
> `[C++11: 8.5.1/16]:` The semantics of initializers are as follows. The *destination type* is the type of the object or reference being initialized and the *source type* is the type of the initializer expression. The source type is not defined when the initializer is a *braced-init-list* or when it is a parenthesized list of expressions.
>
> - If the initializer is a *braced-init-list*, the object is *list-initialized* (8.5.4).
> - [...]

And I shan't quote it all, but `[C++11: 8.5.4/3]`, where *list-initialization* is defined, is where our story ends. It shows that without an initializer-list constructor, and given that your list has two elements (not one and not zero), your program is ill-formed.

GCC actually *doesn't* accept your program ([example](http://rextester.com/MRC69655) thanks to Igor), though clang erroneously does ([example](http://rextester.com/SND40913), same credit).

> If you are right, these are some terrible news for simple structures because I tend to use default initialization everywhere: `struct A { double x{}, y{}; };`

Yep, time to stop doing that, if you want your C++11 classes to be aggregates. :)

C++14 actually removed the *brace-or-equal-initializers* restriction from `8.5.1/1`, so switching to a newer standard will get you where you want to be.

Comment: The real problem here is C++'s absurd complexity breeding wholly inevitable confusion.

Comment: Newer standard? I am using Visual Studio Professional 2015 Update 3 (so C++ 14): same error.

Comment: @Liviu: [Visual Studio doesn't really track standards in unitary chunks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx#cpp14table). I'll bet this is a change in C++14 that it just hasn't followed yet. If you run the GCC testcase with `-std=c++14` you should see it working, though.

Comment: sorry for wasting your time, but I do not see how people who use Visual Studio (like the tag clearly say it) can "switch to a newer standard" (it is like saying: "switch to a newer space shuttle" - oh, there is none ... then go to Russia!) and thanks for the cryptic table (by elimination I suppose you talk about "NSDMIs for aggregates")

Comment: @Liviu: I make no promise that they can! They have to take that up with Microsoft, not with me. I'm only telling you what the C++ standard defines, and that you need to use the C++14 version of this "feature" to get rid of the error message. How you go about doing that is your own business! (Similarly, I'm not pointing to anything specific in the table; I'm just proving that VS 2015 doesn't implement all of C++14; if you want docs on specific features, then you can find them yourself.) The important part of this answer is that VS is correct about C++11 (with which the question is also tagged).

Comment: Thank you, not the first time you helped me, the third time I'll try to use this PayPal system

Comment: While [VS2015 Update 3 did add standards version switches](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/06/07/standards-version-switches-in-the-compiler/) they largely affect just the standard library AFAIK. Any new behavior will have to come in vNext, as is the usual case for MSVC.

Comment: It will be done in the next VS version, AFAIU
[C++14/17 Features and STL Fixes in VS “15” Preview 5](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/10/11/c1417-features-and-stl-fixes-in-vs-15-preview-5/)