# Cannot convert from 'initializer-list' to UserController

Tags: c++, class, oop, compiler-errors, initializer-list

I have this class:

```
class UserController
{
private:
    Repo repo;
    Repo adoption;
public:
    UserController(const Repo& r, const Repo& a) : repo(r), adoption(a) {}

    Dog get(int index) { return this->repo.get(index); };
};
```

When I try to create an object of type UserController, like this:

```
UserController controller{ repo1, repo2 };
```

it gives me the error: "error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'initializer-list' to 'UserController'". Why?

Comment: Did you compile with C++11 turned on?

Comment: visual studio? see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38065676/possible-msvc-2013-bug-when-initializing-struct-members

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) to compile this code.

Below I am compiling without C++11 support and with (which succeeds).

```
Georgioss-MacBook-Pro:~ gsamaras$ g++ main.cpp 
main.cpp:14:20: error: no matching constructor for initialization of
      'UserController'
    UserController controller{ repo1, repo2 };
                   ^
main.cpp:2:7: note: candidate constructor (the implicit copy constructor) not
      viable: requires 1 argument, but 0 were provided
class UserController
      ^
main.cpp:8:5: note: candidate constructor not viable: requires 2 arguments, but
      0 were provided
    UserController(const Repo& r, const Repo& a) : repo(r), adoption(a) {}
    ^
main.cpp:14:30: error: expected ';' at end of declaration
    UserController controller{ repo1, repo2 };
                             ^
                             ;
2 errors generated.
Georgioss-MacBook-Pro:~ gsamaras$ g++ -std=c++0x main.cpp 
Georgioss-MacBook-Pro:~ gsamaras$
```

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio 2013, so I'm not quite sure if I'm compiling my code with C++11. It works for one argument, but I don't know why it doesn't work for two...

Comment: @Xyntell and? What was it?